# Lua stack on iOS device only has ?, and not class names or line numbers

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk, stack-trace, testflight

I'm debugging an app made in Corona on an iOS device. We've passed our app out for testing via test flight around the office, and given our testers a little xCode tutorial, so they can give us the device log when a bug happens. But now, when they send us a bug report, we notice that there are no class names or line numbers in the stack trace -- so it's impossible to tell where the bug is coming from. It looks like this:

```
Feb 26 17:39:01 Daniels-iPad ABC096-apple[3106] <Warning>: ?:0: attempt to get length of upvalue '?' (a nil value)
        stack traceback:
                ?: in function 'addBody'
                ?: in function 'createObstacle'
                ?: in function 'spawnOne'
                ?: in function 'spawn'
                ?: in function 'conditionalSpawn'
                ?: in function 'begin'
                ?: in function '?'
                ?: in function 'handleAdded'
                ?: in function 'add'
                ?: in function 'createObstacleSpawner'
                ?: in function <?:210>
                (tail call): ?
                ?: in function '?'
                ?: in function <?:148>
                ?: in function 'listener'
                ?: in function 'dispatch'
                ?: in function 'tellViews'
                ?: in function '?'
                ?: in function <?:151>
```

Not very helpful! However, I know that in the past I have seen more helpful stack traces when loading my app onto my device directly from my computer -- and not over the internet, via test flight. Is there any way to distribute the app and still get good stack traces? Is it at all related to the dSym file that comes with my app, when I build it in Corona? Help me, Obi Wans, you're my only hope! What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding [lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107090/lhf) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28744706/1150918), by default Corona strips debug info in distribution builds and leaves it on debug builds. [1]

So, You'd probably want to create/edit `build.settings` file and set this up:

```
settings =
{
    build =
    {
        neverStripDebugInfo = true
    }
}
```

That would prevent stripping of the `debug` info in any type of builds.

Extra information how exactly testers does those builds might also help.

[1] http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#buildcontrol

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how Corona works, but it seems that your script has been precompiled and stripped of the debug information maintained internally by Lua.

It is not related to dSym or anything external.